# Cannot deploy flow, Getting error 'Screen component 'ComponentName' is missing a type mapping 'T'

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, deployment, generics, screen-flow

I have created a [flow screen component that work for multiple object](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_extend_generic_sobject.htm). In the flow, I have created a collection variable. I have created an LWC component that uses the collection variable.

When I try to deploy the flow in a different org (which already includes LWC component), I get a deployment error
***'Screen component 'Show_Selection_Menu' is missing a type mapping 'T'.'***

This is my TargetConfig

```
<targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
        <propertyType name="T" extends="SObject" label="Object Name" description="Select SObject API NAME" />
        <property name="selectionList" label="List of items" type="{T[]}" />

        <property name="selectedItem" type="String" label="selectd" description="Selected item"/>
    </targetConfig>
```

In the flow, I created selectionList of customobject type. I can deploy my LWC component. In the flow, I have shown my LWC component. I cannot deploy my flow.

Any help, idea on how i can deploy the flow?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error, perhaps the following will work. What I presume to be the case is that you have a sourceApiVersion lower than 49 specified in your sfdx-project.json file. Set it to 49 (i.e. Summer '20) or higher and the config file will know what new metadata types it has to push (and pull).